# Is medium trust and partial trust the same thing?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have to host a [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) service in a medium trust environment. I want to know which bindings are supported while hosting WCF services in medium trust. There is a MSDN 
article, *[Supported Deployment Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412171.aspx)* which talks about partial trust. Is it the same as medium trust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Full trust; you can do anything.
- High; you can do anything except unmanaged code, services, event logs, msmq, odbc/oledb/oracle.
- Medium; same as High,  with the additional restrictions of not being able to access files outside the wwwroot, access the registry, or do network/webservice calls.
- Low; same as Medium, with the additional restrictions of not being able to write to the file system and call CodeAccessPermission.Assert.
- Minimal; no access, except execution.

> If an application is configured with a trust level other than Full, it is referred to as a partial-trust application. Partial-trust applications have restricted permissions, which limit access to secured resources for the application.

Source: [trust Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)